# DateFormat.is24HourFormat always returns the same result

Tags: android, date-format, android-timepicker

I have a `TimePicker` declared in XML

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timepicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I try to set the 12 or 24 hours mode programmatically, but the picker always shows on the same hours format.

```
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
timePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
timePicker.setCurrentMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));                 
timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(ctx)); //TODO bug
```

`is24HourFormat` always returns the same value if I change my locale from English to Italian.

Comment: Have you tried to turn off 'Use 24-hour format' in Settings -> Date & time?

Comment: 24-hour format is independent of locale. Instead, it uses the system setting as mentioned on the comment & answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings and make sure that you have checked "Use 24-hour format" as shown in screenshot.

[image: Android settings]